# Speeding up USB 3.0 on my machine, Vantec USB3.1 to PCI card is slower than MOBO ports?

Tags: windows-7, usb, performance, pci-express

So I read an [article on Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/usb-3-uas-turbo,3215-5.html) after I was tired of waiting for some backups to complete faster. Admittedly I did not understand parts of the article but what I took away from it is that I could buy a UASP enabled USB to PCI card to get some more transfer speed.

I ended up buying a [Vantec USB 3.1 to PCI](http://www.vantecusa.com/en/product/view_detail/669) card and installing it. Prior to the card I was using my MOBOs ([Evga Z77 FTW](http://www.evga.com/articles/00677/)) ports and was getting ~70Mbps, when using the card I now get a few spikes of almost 60 Mbps.

I take it that I did not read the Tom's Hardware article correctly and missed something? Why is this card slower than I had expected?

Also, not really part of the question but take a shot at it if you want. I forgot that my 6th PCI lane wouldn't work without a power cable plugged into a second adapter for it. So I turned off my computer (not the PSU) and with the SATA power still plugged into the card I moved it from slot 6 to slot 3. Right when the pins connected in the PCI slot the computer started to boot up ...? Is this some random issue or known?

Comment: You installed it in a PCI slot or a PCI Express x4 slot.  There is a huge difference.  *If I didn't want a clarification I wouldn't ask.*  Your second part of your question isn't clear.  Feel free to clarify it.

Comment: PCIe x16. I will try to clarify the second part.